# CRM 2011 - Set Lookup Value with just Name

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011

I have huge amount of records in Excel and have to tranfer those records to CRM. Some of them are lookup value. I just have got their "Name's", not ID's. Is most efficient way; first retrieve Record ID from Name, then transfer? Or is there any another possible way?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: you can do with the standard import functionality, it can map the record using the name (better if you have not duplicate names inside CRM for that lookup)

Comment: No, It will be console application. It will start every first day of month (Scheduled Task).

Comment: the retrieve all the records and use a dictionary<guid,string> and implement your logic in case of duplicate names

Comment: Is there any other way to transfer without retrieve?

Comment: you can start also an import job by code, but you need to check msdn for the details (I don't remember the message names right now)

Comment: Under the hood whatever method you use to import the data must retrieve the ID before creating the new records.. so the answer to your latest question is no.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the import data functionality which CRM provides out of the box. Be sure to map the names with the name value of lookup.

Comment: I commented under my answer. It will be a console application. It should execute first day of every month. Please read comments first then answer.